# Change javascript toggle script to highlight active state

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I change this [js toggle script](http://jsfiddle.net/7v7ys/1/)

```
$('#toggle > span').click(function () {
var ix = $(this).index();

$('#first').toggle(ix == 0);
$('#second').toggle(ix == 1);
$('#third').toggle(ix == 2);
});
```

so the "active toggle" or "clicked toggle"  is highlight in a different color eg red. ( For example: I want "First" to be highlighted in red because that is the default state and "first CONTENT" is displayed. When a user presses "Second" to display "second CONTENT" I want "first" to return back to it's inactive state (blue) and "second" to be highlighted in red because "second CONTENT" is being displayed and so on...  )

Many thanks to all you geniuses!!

Update

I have implemented the script on a test html page head body etc. and all works fine but I actually need to use it inside and article on a joomla site and it does not seem to work. This is the code I put inside the Joomla article (with the associated css added to the template css file).

```
<p id="toggle"> 
<span class="active"> <a href="#">First</a></span>
<span> <a href="#">Second</a></span>
<span> <a href="#">Third</a></span>

</p>
<div id="first">first CONTENT</div>
<div id="second">Second CONTENT</div>
<div id="third">Third CONTENT</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

$('#toggle > span').click(function () {
var ix = $(this).index();
$('#toggle > span').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');

$('#first').toggle(ix == 0);
$('#second').toggle(ix == 1);
$('#third').toggle(ix == 2);
});

</script>
```

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7v7ys/2/ ?

Comment: @Mr.Alien Post it as an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @ Nicolas, @ Mr. Alien What am I missing? Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign an `active` class to the first menu item, and add two lines before your code as follows

```
$('#toggle > span').click(function () {
    var ix = $(this).index();
    $('#toggle > span').removeClass('active'); //Remove active clas from all span elements
    $(this).addClass('active'); //Adds active class to the one which was clicked

    $('#first').toggle(ix == 0);
    $('#second').toggle(ix == 1);
    $('#third').toggle(ix == 2);
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7v7ys/2/)

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/7v7ys/5/) *(Inactive ones will be blue, as commented)*

It would be better if you use `data-` attributes to toggle between the elements instead of using ids if you are having dynamic tabs.

Comment: Don't forget, he wants unselected ones to be blue.

Comment: @Nicolas Thanks, added another demo

Answer (score 0):

If this code is inside your firsts toggle function this will change the elements CSS.

```
<style>
.active {
background-color: red;
}

.inactive {
background-color: blue;
}
</style>
```

The below code would go inside your elements click function.

```
// reset css of other elements to unselected

$('#first').removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');
$('#second').removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');

// set the selected elements class to active
$(this).addClass('active');
```

Comment: Would be better to toggle a class.

Comment: @ Nicolas..Thanks man. Is it possible for you put an example in jsfiddle? Cheers!

Comment: @Nicolas... Cancel that!... I think i got it... Cheers again!